# How to access this JSON value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I have no idea how to access certain value in JSON string. I had lsit of these objects and I did access them by looping through with `$.each` function. But it does not seem to work here. I've tried to do `alert(data.type);` but it gives me `undefined` variable.

TL;DR: 
This is JSON string that I get via AJAX. How can I access `type` value in JavaScript using jQuery?

```
{
    "parent_id": "100003381460677",
    "type": "post",
    "title": "a",
    "body": "b",
    "date_normal": "01 May 2012"
}
```

Comment: You have to parse the JSON first (explicitly or implicitly, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript). Then you have a JavaScript object which I assume you know know how to work with.

Comment: @FelixKling yea, I didn't know that I need to parse it. Thanks, now it  works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseJSON` helps you

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name );
```

Comment: Correct one, I was using plugin that did return it as string, not JSON, that's why it went undefined. When I parsed the string to valid JSON it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this JSON data comes from an AJAX call make sure that you have specified the correct data type (`json`) if your server is not configured properly to send the correct `Content-Type` response header:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.type);
    }
});
```

Then the argument passed to the success callback will already represent a javascript object (deserialized by jQuery automatically from the server response JSON string). And once you have a javascript object you could directly access its properties by name. In the example you have shown it is a simple object, not an array. So you could directly access the properties by name.

Answer (score 0):

presuming you use this as your ajax callback:

```
function(data){ ... }
```

You can access it with dot notation:

`data.type`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) (this will automatically parse the AJAX response as a JSON object) then

```
$.getJSON("<url>", function(data, status) {
     $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
          console.log(elem.type);
     });
});
```

Note that the first argument to the callback in [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is the index in the array, not the element itself (that's the second argument).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following two threads;

[Find value in Json by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704026/find-value-in-json-by-javascript)

[how to get distinct values from json in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517519/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-json-in-jquery)

I hope it helps.