# How to iterate a json string made up of list

Tags: jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access this JSON value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397019/how-to-access-this-json-value)

i have the following json string generated from my Spring mvc controller of a list.
How can acces the holidayName property in jquery.

```
[{"holidayId":1,"holidayName":"Raksha Bandhan",
  "holidayStartDate":"Aug 2, 2012 12:00:00 AM",
  "holidayEndDate":"Aug 2, 2012 12:00:00 AM"},
 {"holidayId":2,"holidayName":"Independence day",
  "holidayStartDate":"Aug 15, 2012 12:00:00 AM",
  "holidayEndDate":"Aug 15, 2012 12:00:00 AM"}]
```

Comment: @Felix how can i do that

Comment: What? Parse JSON? It's in the other question I linked to. Also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+parse+json will contain lots of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var data=[
           {"holidayId":1,"holidayName":"Raksha Bandhan","holidayStartDate":"Aug 2, 2012 12:00:00 AM","holidayEndDate":"Aug 2, 2012 12:00:00 AM"},
           {"holidayId":2,"holidayName":"Independence day","holidayStartDate":"Aug 15, 2012 12:00:00 AM","holidayEndDate":"Aug 15, 2012 12:00:00 AM"}
         ]

   $.each(data,function(index,item){       
        alert(item.holidayName)      
   });
```

Working Sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/5egk2/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to use these values in FullCaleandar events array how can do that.

Comment: @SanjayVerma: What FullCalendar ? I recommend you to ask it as a new question with relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Spring MVC, but you should be careful in observing whether the starting "json string" that you're working with is a ***string*** or an ***object***.

If it's a string, you'll need to use $.parseJSON first as @Felix mentioned.

If it's already an object, then you can access it as directly as @Shyju has done, or like so without the each loop:

```
var input = 
    [
        {
            "holidayId": 1,
            "holidayName": "Raksha Bandhan",
            "holidayStartDate": "Aug 2, 2012 12:00:00 AM",
            "holidayEndDate": "Aug 2, 2012 12:00:00 AM"
        },
        {
            "holidayId": 2,
            "holidayName": "Independence day",
            "holidayStartDate": "Aug 15, 2012 12:00:00 AM",
            "holidayEndDate": "Aug 15, 2012 12:00:00 AM"
        }
    ];

console.log(input[0]['holidayName']); //'Raksha Bandhan'
console.log(input[1]['holidayName']); //'Independence Day'
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/zTeX2/